# Leer Xml Soap desde una variable string php

Tags: php, xml, soap

Tengo una variable que recoge la respuesta `SOAP` de la `BBDD`, y necesito analizar su contenido en vez de realizar otra petición y consumir tiempo. Estoy implementando algo asi como una "caché" y evitar peticiones `soap` continuas.

Mi código:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($resultCache['respuesta_xml']);
echo "<textarea>";
print_r($xml);
echo "</textarea>";
```

El `xml` es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <OutputHeader xmlns="Tras.WS.ExternalGateway">
            <ExternalID />
            <ProcessID></ProcessID>
            <Language>1</Language>
            <Version>1</Version>
        </OutputHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ListadoDisponibilidad xmlns="Tras.WS.ExternalGateway">
            <ListadoDisponibilidadResult>
                <Journeys xmlns="Tras.WS.Interfaces">
                    <Journey>

                    </Journey>
                </Journeys>
                <Error xmlns="Tras.WS.Interfaces">
                    <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
                    <ErrorDescription />
                </Error>
            </ListadoDisponibilidadResult>
        </ListadoDisponibilidad>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Pero me da este error:

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'simplexml_load_string():
>   namespace warning : xmlns: URI Tras.WS.ExternalGateway is not
>   absolute'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente función PHP para transformar XML a un array:

```
function xml2array($xmlObject, $out == array())
{
   foreach( (array) $xmlObject as $index => $node)
      $out[$index] = ( is_object ($node) ) ? $xml2array ($node) : $node;
   return $out;
}
```

Lo usas así:

Prueba a utilizarlo 1 vez y haces DEBUG CON PHP

```
$nuevoArray = xml2array(simplexml_load_string($resultCache['respuesta_xml']));
dd($nuevoArray);
```

Si en este punto sigues viendo un OBJETO en vez de un array lo pasas 2 veces por la función.

```
$nuevoArray = xml2array(xml2array(simplexml_load_string($resultCache['respuesta_xml'])));
dd($nuevoArray);
```

La razón de aplicarlo 2 veces es porque algunas veces lo necesitas depende de como venga el contenido. Yo para un request que hago de unos datos para un proyecto web que tengo, lo utilizo y me funciona perfectamente.

Te aconsejo utilizar el `DEBUG DE PHP` "dd()" para ver en qué forma se ven los datos y aprender la diferencia entre "OBJETO" <-> "ARRAY"
Y verás que los `XML` vienen en forma de objeto `php`.